# Has anyone written Australian history from the perspective of the original inhabitants - the aborigines?

Tags: political-history, cultural-history, social-history, australia

I once read that an aboriginal man from Australia in an ironic gesture planted a flag on English soul and proclaimed it now was a part of the aboriginal empire.

I’m curious as to whether there have been books written on Australian history by Aborigines. I’m curious about their perspective about the English policy of dumping convicts on their land and the subsequent history of their dispossession to the point of not being recognised as a people, despite having lived there for 50,000 years.

Comment: The primary difficulty with such histories is that the people in question did not keep records, so nearly everything we know of the Australian Aborigines in the 19th century was written by the English.  It's hard to get any perspective about the crimes of the English if we rely on English writers.

Comment: @Steve Burnap: Had the oral testimony been believed we would have known a great deal more about what had actually happened. But of course they weren’t as it wasn’t in the interests of the great powers and they were castigated as an unpeople.

Comment: Thing is, some of those Palestinians are even still alive.  You can't go talk to a 19th century aborigine.  I'm not saying it's an unworthy goal.  I'm just saying that it is likely not possible in any real sense.

Comment: @Steve Burnap: Yet people do carry the history of their own peoples. The Zoroastrian *gathas* weren’t written for a millennia. If you don’t go looking, you won’t find ...

Comment: Would [this](http://cstl-cla.semo.edu/rzeller/tln.html) qualify ?

Comment: What preliminary research have you done?

Comment: Aborigine didn't keep keep time and had no concept of it, the past being considered as valid as the present. In such a system it would be difficult to write chronologically as they were only interested in events, not in cause and effect situations leading to events. Cause and effect were to them of little difference so had little bearing on each other. What was important was which event had the most impact on the individual.

Answer (score 5):

Doing some research, the only Aboriginal writer I could find who has written about Aboriginal History (Capital H Western-style history that is) is [Bruce Pascoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Pascoe), in his book on pre-colonial Aboriginal agriculture [Dark Emu](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21401526-dark-emu); admittedly it appears that the book uses evidence from records and journals of early Colonial explorers so this may rule it out for you.

However if you're looking for more traditional histories from Aboriginal peoples (that we in the west would call pseudo-histories), then I believe Burnum Burnum's [Burnum Burnum's Aboriginal Australia: a traveller's guide](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3785935-burnum-burnum-s-aboriginal-australia) somewhat covers this (He's also the guy who planted the aboriginal flag in Dover).

Comment: +1. I don't see why using records from the colonizing power would disqualify such a work.